# RF Transmitter and Receiver circuit controls

Tags: rf, control, transmitter, remote-control, receiver

I'm trying to build a Radio controlled TX and RX circuit (using a 2.4 GHz chip and MCUs), to control a robot with four DC geared motors.

I plan to use four momentary on-off-on switches on the TX side to control each corresponding motor on the RX side, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. From what I understand each momentary on-off-on switch is a "DPDT switch" made from two SPDT switches, so it can control four different circuits. I'm not sure how I should connect them or how this will translate to each channel on the RX end.

What I'm looking to do in simple terms is, when I push a switch up, the corresponding motor will go forward.  When I release the switch and it's in its centre open position, the motor will stop.  When I push the switch down, the motor go in reverse.

Can you explain to me how I can achieve this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Chu Question added

Comment: You will probably find it easier to build this with 2.4GHz modules and a small MCU on each end, which is basically how hobby grade RC gear has worked in recent years.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Why would I need a MCU at each end?

Comment: With packetized 2.4 GHz radios because their interface is complex.  With something else, because it is easier and more versatile than the old ways of multiplexing and demultiplexing.  As with many projects it is best to research existing solutions fitting the application before building anything.  The Holtek parts are not meant to work with RC ESCs.

Comment: @Chris Stratton  It would be easier to build because 2.4 GHz modules are digital and there wouldn't be a need for the encoder/decoder?  I will look into Holtek/ESC compatibility issue.

Comment: You would still need an encoder/decoder, which is part of the role the MCU fulfills.  But the 2.4 GHz chips typically do more by themselves to determine that only correct data gets through.  Frankly I suspect that if you want to run hobby ESCs any more attention paid to the Holtek chips is a waste of time.  Use what the ESCs are *intended* to be driven by - hobby grade RC gear or a custom built functional equivalent, which today most usually means a 2.4 GHz chip and an MCU.  Of course you can buy it more cheaply than you can build it.

Comment: @Chris Stratton As I'm a RC novice I'd really like the experience of building it.  A lot of tutorials etc that I came across were based on 433MHz..  So, from what you've said I take it a 2.4 GHz chip and a MCU is the way to go?  I mean, is that what most people would do, yourself for example?

Comment: Pretty much the only people doing anything other than 2.4 GHz for anything but the cheapest throwaway grade toystore items today are the RC submarine people or those looking for a beyond-line-of-sight lower update rate solution.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Would two Arduino Nanos be ok to use for MCUs?

Comment: The MCU on a nano might be a choice, but an "Arduino Nano" is a larger PCB with things you probably don't want, like a regulator with a fairly high dropout voltage.  It could be useful for initial software work though.

Comment: @Chris Stratton ATtiny?

Comment: Not the 8 pin versions, maybe the others.  But you won't save much over an ATmega, and will make your life much more difficult in the process.  ARM Cortex M0 (and even more capable) parts are taking this over from the Atmel, ST, and other 8-bit parts that were common a few years go.  You will not solve this on any site in the SE network - you need to start looking at radio driver code, learn to drive motors (avoid bipolar devices like L293/L298!!) etc.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I'll keep researching, appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The HT12x modules appear to be very basic and simple contact-closure transmitting systems. If you press the button on the transmitting end, the signal on the receiving end activates.  There is no PWM or other kinds of logic happening here.  If you need PWM, etc, then you need something more sophisticated.